# Restrict local website to selected users

Tags: permissions, users, apache-httpd

Suppose I have two local websites under `/var/www/mysite1` and `/var/www/mysite2` via apache I can access them via `localhost/mysite1` and `localhost/mysite2`.

The pages are for local use only and I have multiple users on my machine, say `user`, `user1` and `user2`. Is it possible, that `user` can view both sites, but `user1` only `mysite1` and `user2` only `mysite2`?

Comment: I doubt it, I'm pretty sure the server doesn't get sent the username. You could do it with http passwords.

Comment: You could also achieve this with a [*Single Sign-On*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) solution, I think; with a lot more effort compared to @Kevin's `htaccess` hint.

Comment: (Scratch that last remark, both solutions probably need some kind of `htaccess`-like configuration.)

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, you could use [`mod_access_identd`](http://web.meepzor.com/packages/mod_access_identd/mod_access_identd.html). It added an `Ident` directive allowing authentication and authorization through the [Ident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident) protocol. The Apache server interrogates an Ident server running on the client machine, which can provide reliable information as long as you trust root on the client machine and the communication between the client and the server.

Nowadays, on the Internet, both assumptions are almost always false: communications can't be trusted without cryptography, and being root on the remote machine is not significant. In your case, Ident would work. I don't see any signs that the module has been ported to Apache 2; I don't know how hard it would be to port it. You would have to run an `identd` server; most Linux distributions ship a couple but don't install them by default.

There's still an official [`mod_ident`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_ident.html), but it only provides logging, not authorization.